# Gmock - InSequence vs RetiresOnSaturation

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I don't understand the following gmock example:

```cpp
{
    InSequence s;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX())
        .WillOnce(Return(10*i))
        .RetiresOnSaturation();
    }
}
```

When I remove **.RetiresOnSaturation()** the above code works the same way - **GetX** returns 10, 20 and so on. What is the reason to use **.RetiresOnSaturation()** when we also use **InSequence** object ? Could you explain that ?

Comment: I think this was a copy-paste issue where the writer forgot to edit the second example because it worked when run.

Answer (score 2):

In the exact example given `RetiresOnSaturation()` doesn't change anything. Once the final expectation in the sequence is saturated that expectation remains active but saturated. A further call would cause the test to fail.

`RetiresOnSaturation()` is generally used when overlaying expectations. For example:

```cpp
class Turtle {
  public:
    virtual int GetX() = 0;
};

class MockTurtle : public Turtle {
  public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(GetX, int());
};

TEST(GmockStackoverflow, QuestionA)
{
    MockTurtle turtle;

    // General expectation - Perhaps set on the fixture class?
    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX()).WillOnce(Return(0));

    // Extra expectation
    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX()).WillOnce(Return(10)).RetiresOnSaturation();

    turtle.GetX();
    turtle.GetX();
}
```

This property can be used in combination with `InSequence` when the sequence of expected events overlays another expectation. In this scenario the last expectation in the sequence must be marked `RetiresOnSaturation()`. Note that only the last expectation needs to be marked because when an expectation in sequence is saturated it retires the prerequisite expectations.

The example below demonstrates how this might work out in practice. Removing `RetiresOnSaturation()` causes the test to fail.

```cpp
TEST(GmockStackoverflow, QuestionB)
{
    MockTurtle turtle;

    EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX()).WillOnce(Return(0));

    {
        InSequence s;
        EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX()).WillOnce(Return(10));
        EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX()).WillOnce(Return(10)).RetiresOnSaturation();
    }

    turtle.GetX();
    turtle.GetX();
    turtle.GetX();
}
```

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, some (ok, possibly many) developers have a problem, like a gtest error message, discover that `RetiresOnSaturation()` makes the problem go away, and then get into the habit of liberally sprinkling `RetiresOnSaturation()` throughout their unit tests – because it solves problems. This is apparently easier than reasoning about what the test case is supposed to accomplish. On the other hand, I like to think in terms of what has to happen (according to the *documented* API contract) in what order – which can be a partial order if you use `After()` or don't have everything in the same sequence – and that makes more expressive constructs like `InSequence` or `After()` come naturally to my mind.

So, as Adam Casey stated, there is no technical reason, but IMO there could be an issue of magical thinking or insufficient training.

I recommend avoiding `RetiresOnSaturation()`. There are some general issues with it (like causing confusing warning messages, see example below), but mostly it is too low level when compared to the alternatives, and is almost never needed if you have clean contracts, and use the previously mentioned alternatives correctly. You could say it's the `goto` of gtest expectations…

Addendum A: Example of when a gratuitous `RetiresOnSaturation()` makes for worse messages, and yes, I have seen such code:

```
EXPECT_CALL(x, foo()).WillOnce(Return(42)).RetiresOnSaturation();
```

If `x.foo()` is called more than once, let's say twice, then, without `RetiresOnSaturation()`, you would have received an error message like "No matching expectation for foo() … Expected: to be called once … Actual: called twice (oversaturated)", which is about as specific as possible. But because of `RetiresOnSaturation()`, you will only get an "Unexpected function call foo()" warning, which is confusing and meaningless.

Addendum B: In your example, it is also possible that a refactoring to use `InSequence` was made after the fact, and the person doing the refactoring didn't realize that `RetiresOnSaturation()` was now redundant. You could do a "blame" in your version control system to check.